# Storing array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to store multiple values (integers) in my database field. For that i use

```
serialize :subtype, Array
```

whenever i submit a form i get this parameters for subtype

```
"subtype"=>["",
 "1",
 "3"],
```

Now i try to save this values into my database. So i try to do something like that

```
@request.subtype << params[:subtype][1] << params[:subtype][2]
@request.save
```

Of course it doesn't work. How can i do that? How to store these values.
This is my migration:

```html
create_table :requests do |t|
   ....
   t.integer :subtype
   ....
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
```

In my form i have:

```html
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :subtype, 
RequestType.order(:typeName), :RequestSubTypes, :typeName, :id, :subTypeName, 
{include_blank:false},{:class => "subTypes", multiple: true }  %>
```

Comment: What DB you are using ?

Comment: Can you post your `migration` file where you added `subtype` and actual `params`?

Comment: I am not sure but I think `t.integer :subtype` your `subtype` field should be of text type `t.text :subtype`

Comment: @Sontya, text? not a string?

Comment: yes `text` not a `string`. Because `:string` is `VARCHAR` type with `limit` of 1 to 255. So it will be better to go with `text` which allows `TINYTEXT, TEXT, MEDIUMTEXT, LONGTEXT2` with `limit` of 1 to 4294967296

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73066/discussion-between-sontya-and-user3565829).

Comment: Regardless of the intended use, it is always cleaner to store such fields in a new table, which references the original table (1-n relation). It is also easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize field can't be `integer` type.So change it to `text` type

Run this migration

`rails g migration add_subtype_to_requests subtype:text`

```
class Migration000000
    def change
        add_column :requests, :subtype, :text
    end
end
```

Then this should work for you

```
@request.save
```

**EDIT**

In your controller allow subtype array

```
def request_params
   params.require(:request).permit(:field1, :field2, :subtype => [])
end
```

Comment: now my db cell have these values ---
- . Should it be like that?

Comment: No, it should be a proper `array`

Comment: I think you `params[:subtype]` are not getting passed correctly. Check or post `form` which you are submitting and check if you are using `strong parameters` then you should allow `subtype` in the params

Comment: You have one method in controller which will be creating `request_params` in that method allow `subtype`

Comment: seems like it works. should it store array like that ---
- ''
- '1'
- '2'

Comment: try accessing it from console, what you get `@request.subtype`

Comment: how could i reject blank array element. I tried .reject as has been proposed, but it doesnt work

Comment: Try this `params[:subtype].reject! { |s| s.empty? }`

Comment: oh ye, i get ["", "1", "2"]. I worked. Thanks. If you know how to ject blank element could you help me?

Comment: it sais "undefined method for nil"

Comment: You can try params[:subtype].reject! { |s| s == ""}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to append to the column, just do this:

```
@request.subtype = params[:subtype].reject { |st| st.blank? }
@request.save
```

As sub_type is an array, this is all you need to do.

Comment: Actually that will store the blank value too, I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Seemst that it works, but when i check my db cell, it is empty. Should it be like that? How array should be presented in my db cell.

Comment: I just updated my answer to reject blank values. Odd the DB cell is empty, try outputting params[:subtype] to the console - does it have a value? Depending how you are submitting your form it's possible you need to use params["subtype"]

Comment: params[:subtype] is nil, so adding .reject raises an error.

Comment: i tried to use "subtype" but it raises an error( undefined)

Comment: Log 'params.inspect' (no quotes). What's the output?

Comment: subtype:
  - ''
  - '1'
  - '2'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73065/discussion-between-richardae-and-user3565829).